# Programmatically read the pod information in PHP code

Tags: php, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have small php application deployed in Kubernetes as deployment pod. And I want to know in php code, in which environment (dev, sit or uat etc) the pod is deployed.
I tried to read the environment variable via deployment.yaml file. But it is not printing.
Another option is that I have the namespace name with env name prefixed, So, I am able to read kubernetes namespace information where the php pod is deployed, also will be helpful. How can I achieve in index.php or any other php file.?

Comment: ***deployment.yaml file***
`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: **sit-assetservice-php-deployment**
  namespace: namespacename
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: assetservice-php
spec:
        **  env:
            - name: profile
              value: sitliveblue**`

Comment: **assetservice.php**

`$var = $_SERVER["profile"];
echo $var."profile";

echo $_SERVER["profile"];
echo getenv("profile")."<br>";

print "env via \$_ENV is: ".$_ENV["profile"]."\n";
print "env via \getenv is: ".getenv("profile")."\n";
print "env via \$_SERVER is: ".$_SERVER["profile"]."\n";


None of the above statements are printing the profile value.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74343694/edit) the question to include all necessary information (it's what it's for) instead of adding parts as comments. Specially chunks of code, which are unreadable in that format.